# Case insensitive bash string substitution

Tags: bash, shell-script

I'm trying to make a script that will merge two subtitles.

```
file.srt
file.forced.srt
file2.srt
file2.Forced.srt
```

I have a case insensitive for matching both forced subtitles.

```
shopt -s extglob
shopt -s nocaseglob

for file in "${1%/}/"*forced.srt; do
   echo File: "$file"
done
```

I have this code to remove forced string from the filename, so I get the matching file to use in my script

```
subs=${file//.Forced/}
```

How can I remove this string `forced` from my variable, case insensitive?

Comment: Please explain why *four* `.srt` files are listed when the goal is to merge only *two* files.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want [the `nocasematch` shell option](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) here, rather than (just) `nocaseglob`:

> If the `nocasematch` shell option (see the description of shopt in [The Shopt Builtin](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#The-Shopt-Builtin)) is enabled, the match is performed without regard to the case of alphabetic characters.

`nocaseglob` is only for true filename expansion (like you used in your for loop), but doesn't apply to other places pattern matching occurs. For your use case you actually need *both* enabled so that both the filename expansion and the pattern match do it.

For only those two characters in that one spot, [you can use](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Pattern-Matching) `[Ff]` to match both `F` and `f` there.

Comment: Do I use `shopt -s` too to enable this option?

Comment: Yes, it's exactly the same sort kind of thing as `nocaseglob`.

Comment: Would it be possible to get an example please?